# OpenGL transparency in texture when render with stencil buffer

Tags: opengl-es, blending

The question has been updated thanks to the comments.

Screenshot of how textures overlap
[image: Screenshot of how textures overlap]

To draw 2 points with brush texture using the stencil buffer to avoid textures transparency overlap, the following code is used:

```
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST.gluint)

    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT.gluint | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT.gluint)

    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP.gluint, GL_KEEP.gluint, GL_REPLACE.gluint)

    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS.gluint, 1, 1)
    glStencilMask(1)

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS.gluint, 0, 1)

    glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL.gluint, 1, 1)
    glStencilMask(1)

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS.gluint, 1, 1)

    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST.gluint)
```

And stencil buffer works, however, each point fill a full rectangle in the stencil buffer, but a texture image has transparency. So maybe texture used in the wrong way?

The texture is loaded like this

```
    glGenTextures(1, &gl_id)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D.gluint, gl_id)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D.gluint, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER.gluint, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D.gluint, 0, GL_RGBA, gl_width.int32, gl_height.int32, 0, GL_RGBA.gluint, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.gluint, gl_data)
```

Blending set as

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND.gluint)
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE.gluint, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.gluint)
```

Could you please advice where to look in order to fill 1s in stencil buffer by exactly not transparent area of brush image?

Comment: Try `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` `glBlendEquation(GL_MAX)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you for the comment! With such blend, it does not draw at all. I've added initGL code that is used. Please check it out if you would have a chance.

Comment: have you considered using stencil masking? what you do is discard if stencil has been written to, and write to stencil and color otherwise. to clear the stencil so that it can be used by other brushes, render the exact same geometries and reset the stencil bit. apply write mask on color

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your suggestion! Could you please take a look at updated questions with how I use a stencil?

Comment: looking closer it does not look right at all... your glStencilOp says "keep stencil value if fail, replace with reference if pass". first `glStencilFunc` should be `glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, -1)` - "pass if stencil value is not (reference & mask), reference is 1, mask is all ones". this will together with glStencilOp "replace where stencil value is not 1 with 1". all `glStencilMask` can be removed since the default (all ones) suffices. second draw can in your code be replaced with `glClear`, or redrawing with `glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0)` - "always pass, replace with zero".

Comment: ...and you are missing `glColorMask` when unmasking the stencil, causing more opacity than intended for the brushes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to `discard` the transparent parts of the texture in the fragment shader. A fragment can be completely skipped in the fragment shader by the `discard` keyword.
See [Fragment Shader - Special operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader).

Use a small threshold and `discard` a fragment, if the alpha channel of the texture color is below the threshold:

```
vec4  texture_color = .....;
float threshold = 0.01;
if ( texture_color.a < threshold )
    discard;
```

---

An other possibility would be to use an [Alpha test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Alpha_test). This would be only available in OpenGL compatibility profile, but not in core profile or OpenGL ES.

See [Khronos OpenGL-Refpages `glAlphaFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glAlphaFunc.xml):

> The alpha test discards fragments depending on the outcome of a comparison between an incoming fragment's alpha value and a constant reference value.

With the following alpha test, the fragments whos alpha  channel is below the `threshold` are discarded:

```
float threshold = 0.01;
glAlphaFunc(GL_GEQUAL, threshold);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rabbid76, it is exactly what is needed. I am using OpenGLES and it looks Alpha Test is not available in it, so `discard` works.